# sed replace end of line

Tags: sed, linefeed

I'm trying to add a bunch of 0s at the end of a line. The way the line is identified is that it is followed by a line which starts with "expr1"

in Vim what I do is:

```
s/\nexpr1/ 0 0 0 0 0 0\rexpr1/
```

and it works fine. I know that in ubuntu \n is what is normally used to terminate the line but whenever I do that I get a ^@ symbol so \r works fine for me. I thought I'd use this with sed but it hasn't really worked. here is what I normally write:

```
sed "s/\nexpr1/ 0 0 0 0 0 0\rexpr1/" infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 3):

The end-of-line marker is $. Try this:

```
s/$/ 0 0 0 0 0 0/
```

Depending on your environment, you might need to escape the $.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$0=$0" 0 0 0 0 0 "}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file

ruby -i.bak -ne '$_=$_.chomp!+" 0 0 0 0 0\n";print' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$(NF + 1) = " 0 0 0 0 0 0"' infile > outfile
```

Comment: creating another field affects the FS variable. A file with tabs as delimiter for example, will become space. A workaround for this phenomena is to specify a field delimiter that is unlikely to appear in the file eg -F"@#@#"